# Haskell - Pass a function and its arguments as separate arguments

Tags: function, haskell, arguments

I'd like to pass a function and its arguments separatedly

Now I've got a function, lets call it myfunc, that takes a single argument.

I've got another function (func2), that takes multiple arguments, of which the last two are a function (f) and its arguments (a). I cannot pass them together as I need them separatly.

(... represents other arguments)

I've managed to do (SCENARIO I):

```
func2 ... myfunc args
```

But when I try and do (pass SCENARIO I as 2 last arguments to main func2):

```
func2 ... func2 (... myfunc args)
```

I get an error. I believe myfunc is evaluating and the second func2 is getting missing arguments. What do?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this -- can you elaborate your example further? Maybe in the last case you simply want to pass a tuple `(myfunc, args)` instead of the application `myfunc args`?

Comment: What is the type of `func2`?

Comment: @duplode: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a

Comment: ...and then you want to pass `func2` as the argument of type `a -> a`, and the result of scenario #1 as the argument of type `a`?

Comment: yep @duplode, but the result of scenario I cant be evaluated i believe, it seems that a is actualy one argument, instead of three (as ... is a argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get type errors, the first thing to do is to review the types of all involved expressions. Your `func2` has type

```
func2 :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

so the full expression in scenario #1 would be something like

```
func2 n myfunc args
```

with `n :: Int`, `myFunc :: a -> a` and `args :: a` for some `a`. Then you want to do, for some `m :: Int`

```
func2 m func2 (n myfunc args)
```

but the types won't match. `func2` is not an `a -> a` function; you need to supply the first two arguments to get one (by the way, you can also read the type of `func2` as `Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)` - a function of two arguments that results in an `a -> a` function). As for the final argument, `n myfunc args` would mean applying `n` to `myfunc` and `args`, which won't work as `n` is an `Int`, and not even a function. You simply want to pass the full expression of scenario #1, which has the expected `a` type. So scenario #2 might read:

```
func2 m (func2 m myfunc) (func2 n myfunc args)
```

That will at least get past the type checker.